# Is 3-UNSAT problem coNP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np, satisfiability, 3-sat, co-np

The 3-SAT problem, i.e. the problem whether a given Boolean formula consisting of clauses of at most 3 literals is known to be NP-complete. Then it’s complement, i.e. whether such a formula is unsatisfiable, is coNP-complete, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\ell\subseteq\Sigma^*$ be some language. The complement of $\ell$ is$$\ell^c=\Sigma^*\setminus \ell.$$
The class CoNP is complexity class (set of languages)  whose complement is in NP. Formally

$$CoNP=\{\ell\mid \ell^c\in NP\}.$$
[According to this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP-complete), because of $3-SAT\in NPC$, so $3-USAT\in CoNPC$.